# Extract Server Certificates

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, certificate

I want help in getting the apt piece of code to get server certificates - valid and invalid , signed by CA and self signed. Any links and references will be highly appreciated.

I have a UNIX command which gives me what i want but I want the same output using Java. The command in UNIX is like this -

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.gmail.com:443 -showcerts | \
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/$SERVERNAME.cert
```

This returns the (don't know the encryption) chain of certificates on gmail. I want my program to give the exact same information. Print the whole chain of certificates.

Comment: by "exact same information", do you mean a java app should actually execute the same command in shell and display the output?

Comment: No. Not to run the Unix command from java. But, to get the certificates in same encoding as the Unix command.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using the following steps:

- Initialise an `SSLContext` using a `TrustManager` that trusts anything (this use-case is one of the very few reasons to use such a trust manager). This is only if you suspect the remote cert won't be trusted.
- Get an `SSLSocketFactory` from it.
- Create an `SSLSocket` from this factory, using the host name you want to connect to. If you use the host name (and not an `InetAddress`), this will enable SNI on Java 7, so that would be the equivalent of using `-servername` as an additional option to your `openssl` command.
- Start the handshake (e.g. with `startHandhsake()`)
- Get the `SSLSession` from this `SSLSocket`.
- For each `Certificate` in `getPeerCertificates()`:

  - Get its encoded value (as `byte[]`) using `getEncoded()`
  - Convert it into PEM, either:

    - Use BouncyCastle's `PEMWriter`.
    - Use a Base 64 encoder (e.g. Apache Commons), add the BEGIN/END delimiters and split the string with a new line every 64 characters.

Comment: Using the below code. The Base64 String is ALMOST same as the output i receive using my Unix command. When i did a diff between both, i noticed that only two characters were not matching. The character in the original string '+' came as '-' in my java output. '/' came as '_'. Apart from these two, everything else is perfect. Pasting the code here:                                              
for(int i=0; i<servercerts.length;i++)
{
  byte[] certBytes = servercerts[i].getEncoded();
  String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(certBytes);
}

Comment: Don't use `...URLSafeString`, just use a normal base 64 encoder.

Comment: Wrong Base64 function. Base64.encodeBase64String(certBytes) returns correct certificates. It works now. Thanks a lot Bruno.

Comment: Now, i opened gmail.com in the browser. Went to'View Certificate'. Exported certificates at each level(Root, Intermediate and *.com). They were saved as .crt files (Root and Intermediate).Click open the Root .crt file and go to details tab - Copy to File. Next.Select the 'Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)'.The content of this file and the string that is printed by my java file are not same for the root certificate.They are same for Intermediate certificate. The root certificate obtained from java, saved into .cer file and opened it to see a diff cert when compared to the one extracted from browser.

Comment: From what i understand, its only the intermediate certificate that matters. Root certificates may differ based on the Trust source i.e., in case of browser it was firefox cert bundle and for my code it was java cert bundle. That seems to be the reason behind diff root certs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge in the past and made this option available within my library which you can see here: [GitHub - SSLKickstart - Kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart) I thought it might be helpful for other developers to share it here.

**Usage**

```
List<X509Certificate> certificates = CertificateUtils.getCertificatesFromExternalSource("https://stackoverflow.com/");
           
// or get the server certificates as pem format
List<String> certificatesAsPem = CertificateUtils.getCertificatesFromExternalSourceAsPem("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

**Install library with maven**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```